# Mysql 5.7 errors

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, ubuntu

Yesterday my code was working fine, today I am getting these errors:

```
2018-01-23T14:45:38.100645Z 59 [Note] Aborted connection 59 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-01-23T14:45:38.100700Z 57 [Note] Aborted connection 57 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-01-23T14:45:38.101250Z 19 [Note] Aborted connection 19 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-01-23T14:45:38.101266Z 22 [Note] Aborted connection 22 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-01-23T14:45:38.101300Z 20 [Note] Aborted connection 20 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-01-23T14:45:38.101404Z 21 [Note] Aborted connection 21 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-01-23T14:45:38.101409Z 55 [Note] Aborted connection 55 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-01-23T14:45:38.101441Z 58 [Note] Aborted connection 58 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-01-23T14:45:38.102971Z 61 [Note] Aborted connection 61 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-01-23T14:45:38.102978Z 62 [Note] Aborted connection 62 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-01-23T14:45:38.103355Z 56 [Note] Aborted connection 56 to db: 'baza' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

I try to remove MySQL from ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit and install it again... I tried to login to MySQL console and it appears to be working fine..but when I run node.js application and see in /var/log/mysql/error.log I see these errors and my application stops working.

How to fix these errors?

Comment: Maybe a firewall problem?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from this error what root cause could be. But this isn't a programming question, it's a problem with your server configuration.

Comment: Check out https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/ There a few possible reasons listed.

Comment: How to fix errors step 1: figure out what is causing them. You're trying to skip ahead here.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?